# Clicking datagrid buttom programmatically

Tags: c#

What I'm trying to do is: I have a datagrid which is populated. The last column is a button and i have a time countdown which then presses a button and populates the datagrid. I then want to loop the datagrid and press the button programmatically (like a .PerformClick()) action.

**CellContentClick**

```
private void dgView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (toolStrip.Text != "You are successfully logged in ...") {
        Helpers.returnMessage("You are not logged in ... aborting ...");
        return;
    }

    // once found we execute: reportBackFound() and update the database
    //Helpers.returnMessage("Clicked programatically!");
    var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
    string rowId = senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    string rowNm = senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    string rowUi = senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

    if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        try {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("https://www.thesite.com/api.php?getApiData=1");
            XmlNodeList _nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/api/apiData");
            foreach (XmlNode _node in _nodeList)
            {
                if (rowNm == _node["apiName"].InnerText)
                {
                    // here we do an http webrequest to the url: _node["apiUrl"].InnerText we look for: zd_show.cgi? in the html
                    // if we find this it's a success.
                    var success = _useratorRequester.getReportsPage(_node["apiUrl"].InnerText);
                    if (success.Contains("zd_show.cgi?"))
                    {
                        reportBackFound(int.Parse(rowId), int.Parse(_node["apiId"].InnerText));
                        updateTheLog(int.Parse(rowId), _node["apiName"].InnerText, int.Parse(rowUi), "success");
                    } else {
                        // just update the reports log ...
                        updateTheLog(int.Parse(rowId), _node["apiName"].InnerText, int.Parse(rowUi), "in-progress");
                    }

                    if (chkBoxDebug.Checked)
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText("Debug\\userator-social.html", success, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));
                    }
                } else {
                     // there is no project in the userator system ...
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Helpers.returnMessage("API TASKS:\n\n" + ex.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

**Timer**

```
private void timerCountDown_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter--;
    if (counter == 0)
    {
        timerCountDown.Stop();
        btnParseTasks.PerformClick();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgView.Rows) {
            if (row.Cells["col4"].Value.ToString() == "Action") {
                // perform click event    
                dgView_CellContentClick(dgView, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(0, 0));
            }
        }
        counter = 5;
    }
    lblCountDown.Text = counter.ToString() + " seconds until next check.";
}
```

I know I need to launch the event handler:

`dgView_CellContentClick(dgView, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(0, 0));`

this line is not correct, I'm not sure what to pass in for `DataGridViewCellEventArgs`.

Comment: tried to pass null `dgView_CellContentClick (dgView, null);`?

Comment: Why do you need to launch the event handler?  I usually create a new method if I need to run the same code from both the event handler and other methods.  Then only have in the event handler contain a few lines of code the call a new method.